# Extending an existing DNS zone

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

everyone!

I'm trying something simple at first thought, but it looks impossible when I'm trying to actually implement it.

I want to extend an existing DNS zone in a meaner, so that in my LAN, other than public addresses in this zone would be resolvable.

I'm having Windows 2012 with AD and DNS integrated. I want this DNS to contain the zone example.com in which to add some hosts known only to client PCs on the LAN - these hosts are now added to the hosts file in %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc

And I'm pretty sure I want example.com and not somethingElse.example.com
The thing is that couple of teams are working on same projects. For one of the team anyHost.example.com is visible, because they  kind of hosting the example.com, but don't want to make all the hosts within it public; yet the other team needs access to these private hosts.

I've tried to just add a Primary Forward Lookup zone - which doesn't makes sense, since I'm not hosting the zone - but while I'm having it in my DNS I'm unable to resolve the publicly available hosts - it seems that my local DNS doesn't forward queries that it is unable to answer for that zone. I've added NS record with the real name servers for that zone but it didn't made any difference. Also I've changed the SOA to what I've recieved from nslookup utility (is that correct?). Again no joy. Furthermore I've tried both other types of zones - Secondary and Stub. Secondary zone doesn't loads at all and Stub zone doesn't accept A records so I'm unable to add this special private hosts.

I'm not sure if I can achieve this at all, so I'll appreciate any kind of answers pointing me to the right direction to resolve the mentioned problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to implement split brain DNS (also commonly referred to as split horizon DNS).

For this purpose, a Forward Lookup zone is definitely what you want. When you create a forward lookup zone, the DNS server will (in it's own eyes at least) be authoritative for that namespace. That means, a lookup for any record that might exist in public DNS but not on your internal DNS server, will result in an `NXDOMAIN` response, and the DNS server will not forward a request for, say, `www.example.com` to the real authoritative name server.

Therefore, you might want to pick a subdomain that is not currently in use in public DNS for your internal DNS namespace, eg. `internal.example.com`. That way, the DNS server will act as authoritative for *.internal.example.com, but not for the rest of the *.example.com namespace

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Mathias! I'm already aware of this solution. As I mentioned in the original question I'm interested in extending the `example.com`. Anyways your answer ensures me that this is not possible, although according to my ISP this is totally achievable in Linux environment with Bind. Do you know if this is a limitation of Windows DNS?

Comment: Not afaik. The only way I can think of would be with conditional forwarders for each subdomain, to a second server with an internal zone (once again, split-brain). 

That's a horrible solution, and if you implement it, you didn't get it from me :-) 

If you have a linux box available, you might benefit from dnsmasq - a simple DNS Forwarder that lets you extend namespaces with single entries from `/etc/hosts`